# Connecting to MongoDB from a Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, network-programming

I have a webapp that uses redis and mongo.  This app is deployed in various places at once, and I am learning docker to simplify some of the setup.  The webapp and redis are running in networked docker containers containers.  Mongo is either running on the host or in another server entirely.

I am having trouble getting the webapp container to make a connection with mongo.  When all three are contained in networked containers, it is no problem.

Here is my docker-compose.yml setting up the webapp and redis:

```
version: '3'

services:
    redis:
        image: redis:3.2.1
        container_name: redis
        restart: always
        networks:
            net1:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.2

    webapp:
        image: briyo2289/phythings-webapp:latest
        ports:
        - "80:8080"
        container_name: webapp
        restart: always
        depends_on:
        - redis
        networks:
            net1:
                ipv4_address: 172.19.0.4
        env_file:
        - .env

networks:
    net1:
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
            - subnet: "172.19.0.0/24"
```

My Mongo connect code is boilerplate:

```
return MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err
```

for `dbUrl` I have tried 127.0.0.1, which I didn't expect to work because the container is not the localhost.  I also tried using the public ip address with port 27017.  In addition to trying the public ip address I edited the `mongodb.conf` file so that the bind_ip was equal to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.  (I'm not exactly sure what that did, but it was recommended as a solution in other places.)  Anyways, that didn't work.

When I run `docker-compose up` this is the error I get: `Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [45.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017]`

I'm not sure if the problem is that mongo doesn't want to a remote connecting being made, or if docker is "confusing" my webapp and I am trying to connect to the wrong thing.

Any advice is much appreciated.

EDIT:  Here is the `mongodb.conf` file

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 45.xx.xx.xx
port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#oplog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
#nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com

# Address of a server to pair with.
#pairwith = <server:port>
# Address of arbiter server.
#arbiter = <server:port>
# Automatically resync if slave data is stale
#autoresync
# Custom size for replication operation log.
#oplogSize = <MB>
# Size limit for in-memory storage of op ids.
#opIdMem = <bytes>

# SSL options
# Enable SSL on normal ports
#sslOnNormalPorts = true
# SSL Key file and password
#sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
#sslPEMKeyPassword = pass
```

The only thing I have changed in this file is the `bind_ip` and I un-commented out the `port` just beneath it.

Comment: provide mongodb config

Comment: from `webapp` container, can you tri to curl anything from internet: to confirm your container get access to it.

Comment: @Jean-JacquesMOIROUX  Currently my webapp container won't start without mongo, but previously, when I had mongo running in a networked container, I had the webapp up and running on a live ip address.  I think it's containerized fine, I just can't figure out the switch from container-mongo to host-mongo.

Comment: Yes, run mongo inside container your other containers
`EXPOSE 27017` then ports: 27017:27017 add it to the right `networks: net1` assign IP for exemple 192.19.0.6.
than on your app you can `host = mongo` OR `host = 192.19.0.6`.

If won't work, update your docker-compose.yml with mongo inside